# Best way of handling recreated dialog fragment after activity is destroyed and recreated

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialogfragment

I have an activity which may show some DialogFragments. This activity needs to get the response from the dialogs.
I use a listener. In activity:

```
ProgressMarkDialog dialog = new ProgressMarkDialog();
dialog.setOnProgressMarkSelected(new ProgressMarkDialog.OnProgressMarkSelected() {
    @Override
    public void onSelect(final int a) {
    //some code..
        }
});
```

In the dialog:

```
public void setOnProgressMarkSelected(OnProgressMarkSelected onProgressMarkSelected) {
    this.onProgressMarkSelected = onProgressMarkSelected;
}
```

This code works fine until somehow the activity is destroyed, but the dialog still open. The program will crash with NullPointerException because the onProgressMarkSelected is null.

I can use

```
@Override
public void onAttach(final Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    onProgressMarkSelected = (OnProgressMarkSelected) activity;
}
```

and implement the interface in the activity. 
But if I have few DialogFragments, that means I should implement few interface in the activity and the code will be very messy. 
What is the Android best practice for this case?

Comment: What is disturbing you? The amount of `implements ...` or callbacks in your Activity?

Comment: yes. the amount of implements...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way is to stick to the standard positive/negative buttons and attaching `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` as shown in the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Look at it this way: standard Android user expects to see positive and/or negative button in the dialog. The Activity -if needed- should only be informed about the result (positive, negative input data) of the dialog. Any other input validation should be handled inside the `DialogFragment`

Answer (score 0):

You could use inheritance with interfaces. Because on interfaces multiple inheritance is possible like this:

```
public interface A(){
    void doA();
}

public interface B(){
    void doB();
}

public interface BundleAB extends A, B {
    void justAnotherMethod();
}
```

With this you can bundle your interfaces and use it like this:

```
public class MyClass implements BundleAB {
    @Override
    public void doA(){}

    @Override
    public void doB(){}

    @Override
    public void justAnotherMethod(){}
}
```